# Is it a good idea to create an empty service in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, service, android-service

I want to create an empty service that will just run in the background once a certain fragment is open - the service will fill an array in the background but is not used in the current (calling fragment):

Code to create the service:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(ServiceActions.class.getName(), ServiceActions.GET_LIST_FROM_API);
        intent.putExtra("api_code_id", "12345");
        managerProvider.getRequestManager().startRetrievalService(intent);
```

Register &  Unregister listener:

```
manager.registerReceiver(backgroundListReceiver , new IntentFilter(ServiceBroadcasts.GET_LIST_FROM_API_RESULT.name()));
manager.unregisterReceiver(backgroundListReceiver );
```

Then handle the receiver:

```
        backgroundListReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        boolean result = extras.getBoolean(ServiceBroadcasts.GET_LIST_FROM_API_RESULT.name());
                        // DO Nothing here as the list is loading in the background
                        // and stored in the application class
                    }
                };
```

I do register and unregister it in fragment, I guess I asking is this correct way to do it or is there another better process?  The reason for doing it here is that the chance of the user selecting the list is quite high so I'm trying to preload the list prior to them selecting it.
Code to handle loading list in background:

```
    private void getListInBackground() {
    RequestResponse response = RestAPI.getListInBackground();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        mApp.setBackgroundList(JacksonMapper.deserBackgroundList(response.getResponseString()));
    }
    Intent broadcast = new Intent(ServiceBroadcasts.GET_LIST_FROM_API_RESULT.name());
    broadcast.putExtra(ServiceBroadcasts.GET_LIST_FROM_API_RESULT.name(), response.isSuccessful());
    mManager.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your use case.?

Comment: In the calling fragment I have a button to display the list, so I want to populate that list in background prior to the button being selected.

Comment: There doesnt seem any point in using a Service. U can get and fill the array in the same class itself running in a separate thread. After that when u will press the button make a check whether the array is empty or null.

Comment: The service is making a call to web api to get the list does that make any difference?

Comment: I think you are confused. In your question you talk about `Service` but your code shows a `BroadcastReceiver` and you talk about "registering" and "unregistereing", which is done for `BroadcastReceiver`s, not `Service`s.

Comment: @DavidWasser Hi I have service that runs in the background I was using the  BroadcastReceiver is register and unregister that service, but it doesn't do anything in the fragment but populates a list in the background.  I asking as i'm trying to improve the user experience by populating the list prior to the user opening the list.  I can expand the code if that would help to clarify to question.

Comment: Please post more code and explain what you mean by "empty service". Your question is not clear.

Comment: @DavidWasser Hi David, I've updated the code i'm not using real names or codes, as I don't want them being published.  This give a better idea of what I am doing, I Suppose I'm asking is it a good idea?

Comment: Of course you can run background theads (or use a `Service`) to preload or precache content. Lots of apps do this. I don't understand your use of the term "empty service" and you haven't really shown any code that explains what an "empty service" is, and you don't seem to have a technical problem that you are trying to solve. If this is working for you, then I'm sure it is fine.

Comment: @DavidWasser Ya maybe empty broadcast receiver is better description, it is working and I actually do it quite often which is why I'm wondering if it is the correct approach, well thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand. If the `onReceive()` method does nothing, why do you need it?

Comment: That's what i'm wondering, do I need handle the broadcast receiver for the service or in the getListInBackground() method should I just not send the result broadcast?